# How to use relative paths in typescript shared package with Yarn workspaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarn-workspaces

When using Yarn workspaces with one TS module depending on another, node isn't looking in the `/dist` folder, so cannot find the js files it needs to run.

### More detail:

I'm using Yarn workspaces with the following structure:

```
tsconfig.json
package.json
packages/
  shared/
    index.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    interfaces/
      index.ts
apps/
  server/
    index.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
```

Within apps/server, I want to import something from shared/interfaces/index.js, so I write `import X from 'shared/interfaces'`.

However, the way my typescript is compiled, the `shared` package in the node_modules folder once installed looks like this:

```
dist/
  index.js
  index.d.ts
  interfaces/
    index.js
    index.d.ts
interfaces/
  index.ts
index.ts
index.js
```

So if I import from just the index i.e. `import X from 'shared'`, it's all fine. However, if I try to do `import Y from 'shared/interfaces'` I get an ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND error (because it seems node is trying to pick up `interfaces/index.js` instead of 'knowing' to look for `dist/interfaces/index.js` instead.

How can I get node to look in the dist folder for a relative import?

### My files

Root package.json

```
{
  "name": "supperclub",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": ["apps/*", "packages/*"],
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

Root tsconfig.json

```
{
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "apps/server"
    },
    {
      "path": "packages/shared"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",       
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  }
}
```

Shared package.json

```
{
  "name": "shared",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc --build"
  },
  "files": ["dist/"],
  "module": "CommonJS"
}
```

Shared tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
  }
}
```

server package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.20.1 <19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "supper-club-shared": "*",
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../../packages/supper-club-shared"
    }
  ]
}
```

server tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "composite": true
  },
  "references": [{"path": "../../packages/supper-club-shared"}],
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per nodejs docs you can use subpath exports as described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_exports).

```
"exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./interfaces": "./dist/interfaces/index.js"
  },
```

so on packages.json you might include the following:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
 "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./interfaces": "./dist/interfaces/index.js"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.20.1 <19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "supper-club-shared": "*",
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../../packages/supper-club-shared"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can import:

```
import .... from '{LIBNAME}/{MODULENAME}'
```

Comment: Amazing, solved! Thank you very much